# How to transfer key-value pair on formAuthentication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, forms-authentication

In my login page I creat FA cookie.

I want to add to it the userId.

I then redirect to my default page,

Where I want to read the userId.

I use this two helper methods:

```
public static class NewWebHelpers
{
    public static void CreateAuthCookie(string cookieName, string cookieValue)
    {
        //Get ASP.NET to create a forms authentication cookie (based on settings in web.config)~
        HttpCookie cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(cookieName, false);

        //Decrypt the cookie
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

        //Create a new ticket using the details from the generated cookie, but store the username &
        //token passed in from the authentication method
        FormsAuthenticationTicket newticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
        ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate, ticket.Expiration,
        ticket.IsPersistent, cookieValue);

        // Encrypt the ticket & store in the cookie
        cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newticket);

        // Update the outgoing cookies collection.
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
    }


    public static string ReadAuthCookie(string cookieName)
    {
        //Get ASP.NET to create a forms authentication cookie (based on settings in web.config)~
        HttpCookie cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(cookieName, false);

        //Decrypt the cookie
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

        return ticket.UserData;
    }
}
```

but get `String.Empty` instead of the userId I entered.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a **new authcookie** with `FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie` instead of reading the one which is coming with the request. Try this:

```
public static string ReadAuthCookie(string cookieName)
{
    HttpCookie cookie =   
        HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
    return ticket.UserData;
}
```